# Call Bing Distance Matrix from PHP - JSON input could not be read

Tags: php, json, bing-maps, unirest

In my application I am pulling data from mysql and calling the bing distance matrix service.  While I can get the call to work fine using postman, etc.  Any method I have tried using various cURL methods and unirest have been unsuccessful.    I get back...

> JSON input could not be read

All that said, here is what I am doing...

This is some sample JSON I am using, which is $content...

```
{"origins":{"latitude":"41.654570","longitude":"-71.49605"},"destinations":[{"latitude":"41.172536","longitude":"-71.555274"},{"latitude":"41.18259","longitude":"-71.567168"},{"latitude":"41.341878","longitude":"-71.695282"},{"latitude":"41.356934","longitude":"-71.63798"},{"latitude":"41.361308","longitude":"-71.625706"},{"latitude":"41.347763","longitude":"-71.67328"},{"latitude":"41.373887","longitude":"-71.665345"},{"latitude":"41.488602","longitude":"-71.38332"},{"latitude":"41.493772","longitude":"-71.137993"},{"latitude":"41.486615","longitude":"-71.246164"}],"travelMode":"driving"}
```

It passes in JSONLint beautifully and also works in postman.

$content is built from this base $jsonbase...

```
$jsonbase = array(
    "origins" => [],
    "destinations" => [],
    "travelMode"   => "driving",
);
```

Here is the bit I am using after I get my return from mysql...

```
$url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix";    
$content = json_encode($jsonbase);

$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Length' => strlen ($content),
                'key' => 'THISISMYKEY');

$body = Unirest\Request\Body::Json($jsonbase);

$response = Unirest\Request::post($url, $headers, $body);
```

I must be missing something, I just can't for the life of me figure it out.  In postman, I have the header keys setup the same.  and for the body I have chosen type as raw and content as JSON. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: The above JSON is what exactly? `$jsonbase` or `$content` or `$body`, also are you sure the result of `json_encode` and the `...\Body::Json`` is the same? if not using strlen of one and actually sending the other might be a problem, resulting in incomplete JSON.

Comment: Sorry, the JSON above is $jsonbase.  when I print_r(json_encode($jsonbase)) and print_r($body, the contents are identical).

Comment: Yes, but then `$jsonbase` IS already JSON, if you encode it as JSON (again) it will not be useful... You should just sent `$jsonbase` to the service.

Comment: It isn't though...    '$jsonbase = array(
    "origins" => [],
    "destinations" => [],
    "travelMode"   => "driving",
);'

Comment: But then `$jsonbase` is NOT the JSON you show above :D That's why I was asking. So the JSON above is actually `$content` I assume?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Spinng in circles at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166559/discussion-between-christianm-and-jkuhns5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out via chat, the problem is that the API requires `origins` and `destinations` to be an array of lat/lng, but looking closely at the resulting JSON `origins` wasn't because it was a single value in the original data.

So putting the single `origin` tuple into an array solved it, resulting in this JSON:

```
{
    "origins": [{
        "latitude": "41.654570",
        "longitude": "-71.49605"
    }],
    "destinations": [
        {
            "latitude": "41.172536",
            "longitude": "-71.555274"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.18259",
            "longitude": "-71.567168"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.341878",
            "longitude": "-71.695282"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.356934",
            "longitude": "-71.63798"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.361308",
            "longitude": "-71.625706"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.347763",
            "longitude": "-71.67328"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.373887",
            "longitude": "-71.665345"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.488602",
            "longitude": "-71.38332"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.493772",
            "longitude": "-71.137993"
        },
        {
            "latitude": "41.486615",
            "longitude": "-71.246164"
        }
    ],
    "travelMode": "driving"
}
```